# Magento 2 add to cart button validation

Tags: addtocart

How can I keep Add to cart button disable until end user filled all the required option for product??

For e.g. If products has required attributes like color and size then at first add to cart button will be disable but once user select the color & size then Add to cart button will enabled automatically.

I think using jQuery this can be done easily but I don't think it's proper way to do so ...is there any Magento way to achieve this??

Comment: Nothing, Actually I'm about to start but know from where to start so I though I better ask....